# How do you get or generate a URL to the object in a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm storing objects in buckets on google cloud storage. I would like to provide a http url to the object for download. Is there a standard convention or way to expose files stored in cloud storage as http urls?

Comment: Are the objects public? If not, how do you want to do authorization?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes. Assuming that the objects are publicly accessible:

```
http://BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com/OBJECT_NAME
```

You can also use:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME
```

Both HTTP and HTTPS work fine. Note that the object must be readable by anonymous users, or else the download will fail. More documentation is available at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris

If it is the case that the objects are NOT publicly accessible and you only want the one user to be able to access them, you can generate a signed URL that will allow only the holder of the URL to download the object, and even then only for a limited period of time. I recommend using one of the GCS client libraries for this, as it's easy to get the signing code slightly wrong: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

Comment: Is it better to use a public URL and link from a website, or use an authenticated service account to retrieve a file and stream it back to a web server to the end user?

Comment: Depends entirely on your needs. Allowing an end user to stream it directly saves bandwidth and, therefore, cost, but proxying it through your own system allows more control.

Comment: Also note that the object name might include slashes (`/`), thus "simulating" an hierarchy (though there is no hierarchy inside a bucket, it is a flat namespace, but some tools might pretend that the hierarchy exist for better visualization.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is not public, you can use this link to the file and it will authenticate with your signed in Google account:

`https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket-name}/{folder/filename}`

Otherwise [generate a signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#download-object):

`gsutil signurl -d 10m Desktop/private-key.json gs://example-bucket/cat.jpeg`

Comment: The first option will only work, if Download Tracking is _disabled_ .

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use https://storage.cloud.google.com// see more documentation at
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#browser