# How to register a URL stream handler for the gs: protocol in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

I have code that must be able to handle "normal" urls like "file:///..." and also "gs://..." files.

I have an application.yaml file that has

`bannedKeywordsFile: gs://myproject.appspot.com/mybucket/myfile.csv`

This fails with a MalformedURLException.

```
@Value("${bannedKeywordsFile}")
private Resource bannedKeywordsFile;

private URL myUrl() {
    return bannedKeywordsFile.getURL();
}
```

To be fair, the Google docs explain this is expected unless a protocol handler is registered.  Is there a handler that can be registered?  Or must one be written from scratch?

Comment: I'm wondering if gcsfuse might be a possibility ... it seems to present GCS files as a mount point for accessing using POSIX and hence file:// might work ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#setting_an_iam_policy_in_your_configuration

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to ignore the Google GCS "url" prefix and access the files using HTTP.  For example:

```
gs://bucket/file
```

can be accessed as:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/file
```

See:

[How do you get or generate a URL to the object in a bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478369/how-do-you-get-or-generate-a-url-to-the-object-in-a-bucket)

This basically *side-steps* the original notion of thinking of `gs://...` as anything special.

Answer (score 0):

`gs` is a scheme that is used for identifying resources stored in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) `Java` [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) will throw an exception if the `protocol` is not valid. Then you got that exception, how you might to use a valid `URL` you might change

```
 gs://myproject.appspot.com/mybucket/myfile.csv
```

to

```
 https://storage.googleapis.com/my-prject-com/mybucket/myfile.csv
```

then later validate with `Java URL` if this is a valid URL.

**UPDATED**

Based what you want to do, then you need to create a `custom validator` so that this validator can be added different schemes,
you might use `UrlValidator` of Apache Common library. Then you can add `custom schmes` by following way:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;


    String[] customSchemes = { "gs", "file" };
    UrlValidator customValidator = new UrlValidator(customSchemes);
    customValidator.isValid("gs://www.somwebsite.org");// true
    customValidator.isValid("file:///home/user/Desktop/fileName.png");  // true
```

JIC, this dependency should be added, if you are using `maven`:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or If not, then for `gradle`

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But using https to access GCS requires additional headers for authorization (403 response code).  These would not be required if gs:// or file:/ were used.  I am looking for something that needs no application code differences to handle the different protocols.